# htaccess ignore specific string in url

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a bilingual website, I want to make htaccess rule for specific condition, my site's primary language is German (de) and secondary is English (en).
domain.com is German and domain.com/en/ is English.

now, I want to add an exception for a page named "xyz" because this page is common for both languages, so if any user types domain.com/en/xyz he should see domain.com/xyz but the url should stay domain.com/en/xyz

This is a WordPress site and I'm using WPML for translations.

Answer (score 0):

This should work but you will need to enable mod_proxy in your Apache `httpd.conf` for that:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en/(xyz.html)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1 [L,NC]
```

Further rules should follow below.